# How to achieve reverse dropship requirement in magento?

Tags: dropshipping

I have dropship requirement like this.

For Example "ABC" is my website. 
ABC says that to all clients or customers :

```
1.) You get an order from your website.
2.)  Go to ABC.com and sign in. Wholesale pricing will appear when you enter your:
Username = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Password = XXXXXX
Use our csv file to upload your orders. This can be found in the wholesale tab.
```

csv format:
PO #    Addressee   Street Address 1    Street Address 2    City    State   Zip Code    Country Shipping Method SKU Quantity

```
3.) We(ABC) ship them directly to your customer.
```

Example:1.xyz got orders from xyz's website.

2.so now xyz will login into abc website and place the orders.

3.now abc will directly  ship to customer.

How to achieve above requirement?

I searched lot of extensions but all are reverse.here the difference is ABC  offering dropship app.

I need to code ? otherwise already any similar extension is there? .Thanks in advance.please comment any clarification needed.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, a client orders at website xyz.com. This website places the order on abc.com, which delivers to the client, who still thinks that xyz delivers.

We do this. We don't use CSV to upload orders, so I'm not going to help you with that. What we do is the following:

- xyz has its own account on our site. We have their logo for invoice PDF on our server.
- xyz orders the items for the client on our website. For shipment address they use the client address. For invoice they use their own. Email is sent to them, not the client.
- xyz is linked to a special customer group (dropshipping). Changing of customer group is disabled for this account, just to make sure.
- We don't normally use the shipment PDF, so we have transformed that. It shows the xyz logo (based on xyz customer id), the shipment address (not the invoice address) plus the normal invoice (not the shipment info). It checks for the right customer group of xyz and it checks if the customergroup change option is disabled.
- The normal invoice still works. We need it for ourselves, for the accountant. We send this to xyz as well. The invoice has a discount that we don't want the customer to know about. The discount makes it impossible to fake the normal invoice PDF.
- On the invoice PDF we have placed a black bar over the address, with a remark that this is a dropshipping delivery.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I don't understand  delivery pdf,normal invoice terms.can you explain? and "for invoice they use their own" means billing address.am i correct?

Comment: With delivery I mean packing slip or shipment PDF. You can create order PDF, invoice PDF, credit PDF and shipment PDF. You can use them all, but we only use invoice and credit PDF. So we transform the shipment PDF into a dropship customer PDF, while the normal invoice PDF is for the dropshipping partner. The dropship partner has to use his own address for the billing address.